# Reshape a matrix to create multiple columns from 1 single column

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like the "main" data frame below:

```
date<-c("2014-01-01","2014-02-01","2014-01-01","2014-03-01")
value<-c(1,2,3,4)
group<-c("a","a","b","b")
main<-data.frame(date= date,value = value, group = group)
main
```

main looks like this. You can run the code and see.

```
       date     value group
1 2014-01-01     1     a
2 2014-02-01     2     a
3 2014-01-01     3     b
4 2014-03-01     4     b
```

Is there a way to make get all the groups from the group column and make them individual columns so my final data frame would look like this with 3 columns.

```
      date       a    b
1 2014-01-01     1    3
2 2014-02-01     2   
4 2014-03-01          4
```

I think what I am looking for is the OPPOSITE of the melt function. But I don't see an UNMELT function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yup!  This is a classic case for the `dcast` function from the `reshape2` package.

The code would be:

```
dcast(main, date~group)
```